# How to remove element after AJAX call in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove a product from my page after clicking the delete button

```
if(products && products.length>0)
  .products
    .row
      h4.col.text-center My Products
    hr
    each product in products
      .row.prod-row
        .col
          | #{product.prod_name}
        .col
          button.editprd.btn.btn-primary(type="button" data-id=product.prod_id data-url="/b/prod/edit") Edit 
          button.delprd.btn.btn-primary(type="button" data-id=product.prod_id data-url="/b/prod/del") Delete 

else
  | You have not added any product in this category.
```

My JQuery looks like this

```
$(document).on('click', ".delprd", function(e) {
        product =  $(this).data("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data("url"),
            type: "GET",
            data: { prodId: $(this).data("id") },
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    $product.remove();
                },
            error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {}
        });
    });
```

Although the product is getting deleted after refreshing the page, I can't see it disappear right after I click the Delete button

Comment: How does the `product.prod_id` value relate to the element in the DOM? Can it be used to select it? If so, then you just need to create a jQuery object from the selector and call `remove()`. If you need an example of this, please add the relevant HTML to the question. Note, HTML not pseudo code or a template.

Comment: Can we see your HTML please, so we can inspect this a little bit better? Also you didn't define variable properly use `const product = $(this).data("id");` and then just pass variable in `url:` and `data:`

Comment: Instead of basic HTML, I'm using pug. The delete button goes like the one I wrote in the question. What should I write inside the success function?

Comment: `$product` is undefined

Comment: Add inside the click handler: `var row = $(this).closest("tr")` then replace `$product.remove()` with `row.remove()`

Comment: @freedomn-m This isn't working either. It's the same problem, the data is getting removed after I refresh but not instantly without reloading

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the `success:` callback?  There's an error in there (as pointed out by @JeremyThille) so either it's not getting there or that's not your code.  Add this as the *first* line in the click handler `$(this).closest("tr").remove()`  Otherwise, as requested, please include the *rendered* HTML - perhaps your "pug" isn't generating an HTML table in which case you'd need to change to the relevant selector, eg `$(this).closest(".prod-row").remove()` (not inside success: as `this` would be different)

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes that fixed my problem!!  Did this ``` $(this).closest(".prod-row").remove() ``` and it started getting removed. Thanks a ton!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Please show me the html of this product with the delete button when we click on the button to remove

change `#{product.prod_name}` to `#{product.prod_id}`

then replace it `$product.remove()` with  `$("#"+product).remove()`;

Comment: The HTML is provided in the question (Well, actually it's Pug, but it gets compiled to HTML)

Comment: There is no #{product.prod_name} in my code

Comment: ```each product in products
      .row.prod-row
        .col
          | #{product.prod_name}
        .col```

Comment: change it in pug file

Comment: Oh in the .pug file. But I have to show the name of product on my page, not the id

Comment: What this ```#{product.prod_name}`` is stand for ??

Comment: IT stands for the product name that is displayed on the page

Comment: If this #{product.prod_name} shows the product name in HTML then keep it.. But add id (same as product id) in the product HTML tag to delete that.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28106613)

Comment: @MartinBrisiak I got the solution in one of the comments. Thanks though. Do I have to mark this as resolved?